# 500 error after update

Tags: errors, updates, 500-internal-error

I had a working (test) blog, and during an update from 3.2.1 to 3.3.1 - something went wrong , I think the update did not finished..

Just before the Update, I have enabled a new theme (all functions and files made by me )

Since the update went wrong - I can not access my admin area (500 error) but the front end works just fine ...

The same blog and theme works without a problem on local machine .

I had deleted ALL files on server (except uploads) and updated with a new version - but to no avail.

any solutions to such a problem =??

Comment: Have you deleted your .htaccess file too?

Comment: Have you tried deactivating all plugins (by changing the names of the folders) and themes?

Comment: @ alex Older - yes , .htaccess deleted as well @m0r7if3r  - I have removed the plugins folder as a whole (renaming that is ) but it is still the same..

Comment: What about your themes?

Comment: only themes there are 2 versions of a theme I made myself , both worked before without problem..and both have no function that has to do directly with the admin area...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In phpmyadmin search :

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_options
WHERE option_name = 'template'
OR option_name = 'stylesheet'
OR option_name = 'current_theme';
```

then :

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'yourthemename' WHERE option_name = 'template';
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'yourthemename' WHERE option_name = 'stylesheet';
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'yourthemename' WHERE option_name = 'current_theme';
```

or if you want to go back to default (presuming some default exists)

```
SET option_value = 'default' WHERE option_name = 'template';

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'default' WHERE option_name = 'stylesheet';

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'default' WHERE option_name = 'current_theme';
```

note :

- template – the “Theme Name” as defined in style.css
- stylesheet – the actual name of your theme folder
- current_theme -the actual name of your theme folder

Comment: Thank you ! it worked ! now i changed to default . When i got to the admin, i got a strange message telling me that the database was needed to be "updated" or "refreshed" - i do not remember . But after that - all worked like charm. life saver ! thanks again

Comment: happy it worked . Once it happened to me too.. I do not know why, but it somehow has to do with changes in the MENU and Categories .

Answer (score 2):

I received a 500 Error message after update the wordpress. However, the problem was not caused by the update process.

Your database server may corrupt a table(s). To fix this problem you should use phpMyAdmin or something else, and optimize/repair the tables.

It Works For Me!

Answer (score 0):

Are there plugin installed?
it's easy to make a 500 error if some plugin does something bad inside an `if( is_admin() )` clause.
Try to remove/rename plugins to isolate the problem.

Otherwise, just remove all files, unzip a freshly downloaded wordpress from wordpress.org, put your uploads back, and retry.

Comment: I have renamed the plugin dir to a temp name, and also reinstalled ..the problem is that I can not even change a theme now , it seems something in the DB searches for an unexciting theme - because after new install wordpress gives me a blank front end (typical of missing theme )

Comment: @Obmerkronen But you should still be able to `/wp-admin` to change your theme. Is `wp-admin` accessible? it should.

Go there and change your theme settings

Comment: this is exactly the whole point of the question - my admin area gives me 500 error. the front end works just fine ..

Comment: If you have no plugins, I really don't know what caused this. But if you can, watch the error logs. The blank page is not just "missing theme": lots of other things could be